# Error: No valid responses from any peers. Errors: peer=undefined, status=grpc, message=Endorsement has failed

Tags: kubernetes, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-js

I m working on hyperledger blockchain and Kubernetes(minikube) on Ubuntu 18-04. In my network there two Organisations with one peer each and the orderer type is Solo. This whole network I deployed on minikube. Chaincode install and instantiation did successfully on pods. After that am trying to invoke by using SDK.

I am using the below code as invoke.js

```
'use strict';

const { Gateway, Wallets } = require('fabric-network');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

async function main() {
    try {
        // load the network configuration
        const ccpPath = path.resolve(__dirname, '..', '..', 'first-network', 'connection1-org1.json');
        let ccp = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(ccpPath, 'utf8'));

        // Create a new file system based wallet for managing identities.
        const walletPath = path.join(process.cwd(), 'wallet');
        const wallet = await Wallets.newFileSystemWallet(walletPath);
        console.log(`Wallet path: ${walletPath}`);

        // Check to see if we've already enrolled the user.
        const identity = await wallet.get('user1');
        if (!identity) {
            console.log('An identity for the user "user1" does not exist in the wallet');
            console.log('Run the registerUser.js application before retrying');
            return;
        }
        
        // Create a new gateway for connecting to our peer node.
        const gateway = new Gateway();
         await gateway.connect(ccp, { wallet, identity: 'user1',discovery: { enabled: true, asLocalhost: true }  });
       
        // Get the network (channel) our contract is deployed to.
        const network = await gateway.getNetwork(channelname);
       
        // Get the contract from the network.
        const contract = network.getContract(contractname);
       
        // Submit the specified transaction.
        // createCar transaction - requires 5 argument, ex: ('createCar', 'CAR12', 'Honda', 'Accord', 'Black', 'Tom')
        // changeCarOwner transaction - requires 2 args , ex: ('changeCarOwner', 'CAR10', 'Dave')
        await contract.submitTransaction('arumnet','argument');
       
        console.log('Transaction has been submitted');

        // Disconnect from the gateway.
        await gateway.disconnect();

    } catch (error) {
        console.error(`Failed to submit transaction: ${error}`);
        process.exit(1);
    }
}

main();
```

configTx.yaml

```
Organizations:
  - &Orderer
    Name: Orderer
    ID: OrdererMSP
    MSPDir: ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/acme.com/msp
    # Policies are mandatory starting 2.x
    Policies: &OrdererPolicies
      Readers:
          Type: Signature
          Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP.member')"
      Writers:
          Type: Signature
          Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP.member')"
      Admins:
          Type: Signature
          # ONLY Admin Role can carry out administration activities
          Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP.admin')"
      Endorsement:
          Type: Signature
          Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP.member')"

  - &Acme
    Name: Acme
    ID: AcmeMSP
    MSPDir: ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/acme.com/msp
    Policies: &AcmePolicies
      Readers:
          Type: Signature
          # Any member can READ e.g., query
          Rule: "OR('AcmeMSP.member')"
      Writers:
          Type: Signature
          # Any member can WRITE e.g., submit transaction
          Rule: "OR('AcmeMSP.member')"
      Admins:
          Type: Signature
          # Either Acme admin OR Orderer Admin can carry out admin activities
          Rule: "OR('AcmeMSP.admin')"
      Endorsement:
          Type: Signature
          # Any member can act as an endorser
          Rule: "OR('AcmeMSP.member')"
    AnchorPeers:
      - Host: acme-peer-clusterip
        Port: 30751

  - &Budget
    Name: Budget
    ID: BudgetMSP
    MSPDir: ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/budget.com/msp
    Policies: &BudgetPolicies
      Readers:
          Type: Signature
          # Any member
          Rule: "OR('BudgetMSP.member')"
      Writers:
          Type: Signature
          # Any member
          Rule: "OR('BudgetMSP.member')"
      Admins:
          Type: Signature
          # BOTH Budget Admin AND Orderer Admin needed for admin activities
          Rule: "OR('BudgetMSP.member')"
      Endorsement:
          Type: Signature
          Rule: "OR('BudgetMSP.member')"
    AnchorPeers:
      - Host: budget-peer-clusterip
        Port: 30851
```

Connection.json

```
{
    "name": "first-network-acme",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "client": {
        "organization": "AcmeMSP",
        "connection": {
            "timeout": {
                "peer": {
                    "endorser": "300"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "organizations": {
        "AcmeMSP": {
            "mspid": "AcmeMSP",
            "peers": [
                
                "peer1.acme.com"
            ],
            "certificateAuthorities": [
               
            ]
        }
    },
  
    "channel":{
        "airlinechannel":{
            "orderers": [
                "orderer.acme.com"     
            ],
            "peers": {
                "peer1.acme.com": {}
            }
        }
    },
    "peers": {
        "peer1.acme.com": {
            "url": "grpc://10.109.214.71:3005",
            "tlsCACerts": {
                "pem": "/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/acme.com/tlsca/tlsca.acme.com-cert.pem"
            },
            "grpcOptions": {
                "ssl-target-name-override": "peer1.acme.com",
                "hostnameOverride": "peer1.acme.com"
            }
        }
    },
    "certificateAuthorities": {
       
    }
}
```

*Logs after running invoke.js*

```
2020-11-26T05:31:09.252Z | connectivity_state | dns:localhost:30751 CONNECTING -> CONNECTING
2020-11-26T05:31:09.252Z | dns_resolver | Resolved addresses for target dns:localhost:30751: [127.0.0.1:30751]
2020-11-26T05:31:09.252Z | pick_first | IDLE -> IDLE
2020-11-26T05:31:09.252Z | resolving_load_balancer | dns:localhost:30751 CONNECTING -> IDLE
2020-11-26T05:31:09.253Z | connectivity_state | dns:localhost:30751 CONNECTING -> IDLE
2020-11-26T05:31:09.253Z | pick_first | Connect to address list 127.0.0.1:30751
2020-11-26T05:31:09.253Z | subchannel | 127.0.0.1:30751 refcount 3 -> 4
2020-11-26T05:31:09.253Z | pick_first | IDLE -> TRANSIENT_FAILURE
2020-11-26T05:31:09.253Z | resolving_load_balancer | dns:localhost:30751 IDLE -> TRANSIENT_FAILURE
2020-11-26T05:31:09.253Z | connectivity_state | dns:localhost:30751 IDLE -> TRANSIENT_FAILURE
2020-11-26T05:31:12.254Z - error: [ServiceEndpoint]: Error: Failed to connect before the deadline on Endorser- name: acme-peer-clusterip:30751, url:grpc://localhost:30751, connected:false, connectAttempted:true
2020-11-26T05:31:12.254Z - error: [ServiceEndpoint]: waitForReady - Failed to connect to remote gRPC server acme-peer-clusterip:30751 url:grpc://localhost:30751 timeout:3000
2020-11-26T05:31:12.254Z - error: [DiscoveryService]: _buildPeer[dsg-test] - Unable to connect to the discovered peer acme-peer-clusterip:30751 due to Error: Failed to connect before the deadline on Endorser- name: acme-peer-clusterip:30751, url:grpc://localhost:30751, connected:false, connectAttempted:true
2020-11-26T05:31:12.261Z - error: [DiscoveryHandler]: _build_endorse_group_member >> G1:0 - returning an error endorsement, no endorsement made
2020-11-26T05:31:12.261Z - error: [Transaction]: Error: No valid responses from any peers. Errors:
    peer=undefined, status=grpc, message=Endorsement has failed
Failed to submit transaction: Error: No valid responses from any peers. Errors:
    peer=undefined, status=grpc, message=Endorsement has failed
```

*Below kubernetes pods setup*
*kubectl get all*

```
NAME                 READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/acme-orderer-0   1/1     Running   0          107m
pod/acme-peer-0      2/2     Running   0          107m
pod/budget-peer-0    2/2     Running   0          107m

NAME                             TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP      PORT(S)                           AGE
service/acme-orderer-clusterip   ClusterIP      10.108.218.191   <none>           30750/TCP                         107m
service/acme-orderer-nodeport    NodePort       10.111.186.82    <none>           30750:30750/TCP                   107m
service/acme-peer-clusterip      ClusterIP      10.98.236.210    <none>           30751/TCP,30752/TCP               107m
service/acme-peer-nodeport       NodePort       10.101.38.254    <none>           30751:30751/TCP,30752:30752/TCP   107m
service/budget-peer-clusterip    ClusterIP      10.108.194.45    <none>           30851/TCP                         107m
service/budget-peer-nodeport     NodePort       10.100.136.250   <none>           30851:30851/TCP,30852:30852/TCP   107m
service/kubernetes               ClusterIP      10.96.0.1        <none>           443/TCP                           112m
service/svc-acme-orderer         LoadBalancer   10.105.155.207   10.105.155.207   6005:30696/TCP                    27m
service/svc-acme-peer            LoadBalancer   10.98.44.14      10.109.214.71      3005:30594/TCP                    56m

NAME                            READY   AGE
statefulset.apps/acme-orderer   1/1     107m
statefulset.apps/acme-peer      1/1     107m
statefulset.apps/budget-peer    1/1     10
```

Comment: Can you add some log output ? I'll add one suggestion below as well.

Comment: @RobEvans I added logs which I got after running invoke.js.

Comment: Did you see my answer below which mentions you've also supplied the incorrect connection.json (referenced by your `invoke.js`). The port numbers clearly do not match connection.json shows `3005` vs whats in the logs `30751`

Comment: Thank you, Rob. yes. I saw that. 3005 this port where I expose my Kubernetes pod. internally it is calling to port 30751

Comment: you need to provide a minimum reproducible example. Without enough detail we're only guessing at what is wrong with the setup. More detail needed on the kubernetes setup you have in place + any additional missing parts

Comment: There is a misunderstanding here, in the connection profile you have mentioned grpc and you have supplied TLS cert. Please use grpcs if TLS is enabled else remove TLS cert if TLS is not enabled and clearly as per the nodejs app logs it is unable to connect to the peers

Comment: I can see that you have used all available services in kubernetes, seems like you are learning kubernetes I strongly suggest that please use docker-compose or swarm and try to setup HLF if works then learn k8s then implement

Comment: I did this setup by using docker-compose. it is working fine. But I have to do this now by using k8s. Can u please help me out with this

Comment: I removed tlsCacerts from connection-profile and used it as "grpc" still it is giving the same error and I m not able to connect the peers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some things to check:

1. `connection1-org1.json` - you've supplied `connection1-org1.json` in the code for `invoke.js` but `connection.json` config as a candidate you presumably expect to be used to load/access the network. Pls confirm if this is correct.
2. `connection.json` - specifies a `tlsCACerts` but the url scheme used is `grpc://` rather than `grpcs://`
3. connection.json - does not specify the orderer url. This may not be necessary if it is discoverable via other means
4. Is TLS enabled on the peers/orderer?

If you can confirm/amend as necessary it will provide a better chance for someone to help.